# Load Javascript Inside Table Element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to perform this javascript inside a table. I just want it to update the text here on load.

```
<td>
    <script>
       $(window).load(function(){
         document.write('it works!');
       });
    </script>
</td>
```

Comment: **<td><script>document.write('it works!'); </script></td>** - but OneofOne's way is better ( separate markup from javascript )

Comment: I need it to do an onload so that I can have the other language I'm programming in make an api call.

Comment: both answers below are employing 'onload'

Answer (score 0):

Why not give that element an id and use that instead?

```
.....
<td id="mytd"></td>
.....
<script>
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('#mytd').html('it works'); //or
     $('#tableid > td').html('it works'); //this will set the html of every td in that specific table
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

set up your code like this:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tdEx"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#tdEx').html('it works!');
})
```

**OR**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#tdEx').html('it works!');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edbKk/7/